# How to make zsh prefer certain filetypes when autocompleting

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I have many files with the same name but different filetype all in one directory:

`foo.aux foo.bbl foo.blg foo.log foo.out foo.pdf foo.tex`

I would like to be able to type `foo[Tab]` and have zsh always autocomplete to .tex, then .pdf, then whatever order zsh likes. Is there anyway of setting this kind of autocompletion preferences?

I am using oh-my-zsh if that is relevant.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Probably asking too much from `_path_files`, which sorts results according to `file-sort` (search "file-sort" in http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html), which could be `size`, `links`, `modification`, etc., just the standard ones.

Comment: For certain commands though, you can write your own completion def to prefer some extensions over the others. Hint: use `files -g '*.tex'` for tex, then `files -g '*.pdf'` for pdf, etc.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thanks very much I will go for that as I am most of the time using vim for my tex files. Understandable that it's not doable generally. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file-patterns` setting to categorize files in whatever way you like. For your case, this should work:

```sh
# First, we define how to categorize the files.
zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns '
    *.tex(D-^/*):tex-files:"TEX file"
    *.pdf(D-^/*):pdf-files:"PDF file"
    *(D-*):executables:"executable file"
    *(D-/):directories:"directory"
    ^*.(tex|pdf)(D-^/*):files:"other file"
'

# Then, we define in what order they should appear.
zstyle ':completion:*' group-order tex-files pdf-files executables directories files

# Finally, we need to enable group names, or the group order won't work.
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
```

Documentation:

- [Glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (`(D-^/*)`)
- [Completion system configuration](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles)